# Android - OkHttp Interceptor call onFailure

Tags: android, interceptor, okhttp

Anyone have any idea how I can call the onFailure callback from the Interceptor class attached to the OkHttp client?

Comment: Try to throw an exception. When an interceptor throws an exception, okhttp calls the onFailure callback

Comment: @warnyul Thanks you're right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to throw an exception. When an interceptor throws an exception, okhttp calls the onFailure callback

Answer (score 2):

@warnyul comment was right. Once I threw the IOException, it triggered the failure.